# Check if next line has more leading whitespace then current line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file structured like this, and I need to read through each of the lines.

```
XXXX
....
YYYY
    ZZZZ
    ZZZZ
    ....
YYYY
    ZZZZ
    ZZZZ
    ....
```

`....` refers to an arbitrary number of the above object.

The file is read into a list named `textList`

```py
lines = enumerate(textList)
for i, line in lines:
    #read in the XXXXs
    if line == "YYYY"
        # from this location, get the next line in lines
        # i.e. (i, lines = lines.__next__())
        # until the next line has the same or lower amount
        # of whitespace than the amount of whitespace before
        # the line that has "YYYY"
```

I've tried this a few different ways, but I keep getting infinite loops. I know this is possible but I just haven't been able to figure it out

Current script: (Giving Index error)

```py
def getIndentLevel(line):
    tabCount = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(' '))
    #print(tabCount)
    return tabCount

textList = ["XXXX", 
            "XXXX", 
            "XXXX",
            "YYYY",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "YYYY",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "    ZZZZ"]
lines = enumerate(textList)

for i, line in lines:
    if line.lstrip(' ') == "YYYY":
        print("YYYY found")
        cur = getIndentLevel(textList[i])
        while True:
            nxt = getIndentLevel(textList[i+1])
            if nxt <= cur:
                break
            i, line = lines.__next__()
            print(i, line)
            #nxt = getIndentLevel(textList[i+1])
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried, that got you in an infinite loop.

Comment: @JosephSible Done

Comment: How do you think that loop would ever exit? I see a `while True`, with no `break` or other means of early exit inside.

Comment: Duh. I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephSible I figured out how to break out, but now I'm getting a "list index out of range" error

Comment: Sounds to me like the list index might be out of range.

Comment: Remember, the `n-th` object of the list has index of `n - 1` so the first item is `0`, then `1`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script solves the problem:

```py
def getIndentLevel(line):
    tabCount = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(' '))
    return tabCount

textList = ["XXXX", 
            "XXXX", 
            "XXXX",
            "YYYY",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "YYYY",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "    ZZZZ",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "XXXX",
            "XXXX",]
lines = enumerate(textList)

for i, line in lines:
    if line.lstrip(' ') == "YYYY":
        print("YYYY found")
        cur = getIndentLevel(textList[i])
        nxt = getIndentLevel(textList[i+1])
        while True:
            if nxt <= cur:
                break
            i, line = lines.__next__()
            print(i, line)
            try:
                nxt = getIndentLevel(textList[i+1])
            except:
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to enumerate.

```
for  i in range(len(textList)) :   
  numWhiteSpace = len(textList[i]) - len(textList[i].lstrip())
  if i == 0:
    continue
  else:
    if numWhiteSpace > (len(textList[i-1]) - len(textList[i-1].lstrip())):
      print(textList[i])
```